# Can a BLE USB dongle be auto-initialised on a simple USB power source?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I wish to setup a location system using BLE but I want to know if a BLE USB dongle on a USB power source transmit basic information to use it for a RSSI based location system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Depending on the make and model. The ones I've used just plug in to a (USB) power source and they work.